# How to display a calculated column value in a form in SHarePoint 2013 site

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013

I've a calculated column(return data type: date and time) in SharePoint 2013 list, am trying to retrieve value and display in a form.
I'm using the below function to get the value from SharePoint list:

```
function getData(g_Data_URL) {
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + g_Data_URL,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function(data) {
              var Onsite= new Date(data.d.Onsite);
                $('#Ontime').data("DateTimePicker").date(Onsite);
},
error: function(error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
```

Please let me know if the syntax of calling the value is incorrect.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From your code, your calculated column name is "Onsite". And I did a test on my end, it works well to get the value:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ct3')/items(1)",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function(data) {
              var Onsite= new Date(data.d.Onsite);
              console.log(Onsite);
},
error: function(error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me explain, initially there is datetime column in which both date&time are getting saved but with a diff of 4 hours. To correct that, I had created another calculated column with formula: =(TEXT(OTime,"hh:mm AM/PM"))+(4/24)
but, by doing this, it is again displaying date and time. Since, I only require time to display, I created another calculated column with formula: =TEXT(ArrivalTime_Timecalculated,"hh:mm AM/PM"), this is successfully showing only time in the sharepoint list, but am not able to display on the form. Please suggest.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap dataptimepicker? Disabled date picker, only time picker?

Comment: yes, bootstrap datatimepicker and I used only time picker

Comment: You should use the date and time calculated column in your code. It should be ArrivalTime_Timecalculated instead of Onsite. Change your code to this: var Onsite= new Date(data.d.ArrivalTime_Timecalculated); Check if this works.

Comment: Yeah, I used the below code and it worked!!! Thanks for your suggestions!!! I was confused with the columns name.
var Onsite_x0020_Arrival_Final = data.d.Onsite_x0020_Arrival_Final;
$('#Onsite').data("DateTimePicker").date(Onsite_x0020_Arrival_Final);

Comment: You could accept my answer if it helps you  :)